# Do i need Administrator priviliges to run an HTA?

Tags: activex, hta

I am trying to install an activex but my user has no admin priviliges.
I saw an artical descirbing that HTA can install activeX as if it is an administrator.
Do i need to be an administrator to run HTA? if not is this not a security loop hole?

Comment: People still use ActiveX? Wow... I feel bad for the users of your site

Answer (score 0):

An HTA file is an application that has the same privileges as a .EXE or a .CMD file. Many people are confused about permissions because an HTA looks like a web page. An HTA uses the same technology as web pages, but it executes locally under the same security model as any other local application.

This means, that if you run your .HTA as Administrator, it can do things that require Administrator privileges. Ordinary users can run HTAs just fine. The security model is the same as for batch files, CMD files, WSH scripts and so on.